# Calculating gravitational effect of a suspended mass on an object within an atmosphere

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

How could one calculate the mass / density / dimensions of a suspended mass to lift an object off the earths surface at sea level with gravity alone?

e.g.

```
   [SUSPENDED_MASS]  (SM)
          |
          | <-- (D) 10 MM air gap
          |
      [A4_CARD] (O)
[FLAT_INDOOR_SURFACE]
```

Some Assumptions:

```
 - Average Air Pressure: 1013.25 millibars
 - Gravity: 9.807 m/s²
 - Object: rigid piece of A4 card measuring 210mm × 297mm (623.7cm^2 surface area?) 
 - Object Weight @ assumed gravity: 25 grams
 - Surface: Flat Indoor surface made of an anti static material with corragation to avoid friction / surface tension / suction
 - Suspended Mass: 1 cubic meter of uranium perhaps? (~19 tonnes) - or would a theoretical weight / density be required?
```

I'm a programmer by trade, so my understanding is this area is limited - this is just a random thought experiment which i'm interested in for a personal project, would like to see what models / formulae exist in calculating this scenario (if any).